# How to insert multiple data types of varying length into variables?

Tags: c++, oop

I need to insert the following values from a text file; however, I am a little confused on how to take in a name that may be of different length in C++ and spaced out differently. This is the Text file contents:

```
    2.5   John Jones
    4.0    Madonna
    3.773   Ulysses S. Grant
```

I was thinking to have a loop that takes in a name then adds the subsequent string to the original name, but does C++ know how to do this and stop reading in when the data type changes? This is what I was thinking:

```
double gpa;
string name;
string temp;
while (file >> gpa >> name) {
    while (file >> temp) {
        name += " " + temp
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that a name should probably be read with std::getline() if you are asking for first and last name because operator >> separates items by spaces.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I use that with a while loop, and does my same idea apply above. Just have another loop that keeps inserting names from the line until there are no more strings?

Comment: Yeah, I know that but the names can be however long. So I can't have a fixed variable for first, middle, and last?

Comment: You could read a line at a time into a string then parse the line.

Comment: A single "fixed variable", a `std::string` will hold a name of any length. In fact, it is big enough to hold the entire contents of all Harry Potter novels, if you so choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `>>` (stream extraction) for the `double`, and `std::getline` for the `std::string`, like this:

```
double gpa;
std::string name;
while (file >> gpa && std::getline(file, name)) {
 std::cout << gpa << ":" << name << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this by defining a type `Name` that reads data as you want a name to be read, but overloading `operator>>` for that type. The `operator>>` for `std::string` stops reading at the first white space, but since you have a type that should include all data to the end of the line, you can define that type, and overload `operator>>` to act appropriately for that type:

```
class Name {
    std::string content;
public:
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Name &n) { 
        return std::getline(is, n);
    }

    operator std::string() const { return content; }
};
```

With that, we can read the data about the way we'd like:

```
double gpa;
Name name;
while (file >> gpa >> name) {
    // print them back out, formatted a bit differently:
    std::cout << name << ": " << gpa << "\n";
}
```